# Python3 Web-scraping cant login to the page? Timestamp?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, timestamp

So i just started to learn web-scraping with python3 and i want to login to this website: https://dienynas.tamo.lt/Prisijungimas/Login

The form data it requires is: 
UserName: username,
Password: password,
IsMobileUser: false,
ReturnUrl: '',
RequireCaptcha: false,
Timestamp: 2020-03-31 14:11:21,
SToken: 17a48bd154307fe36dcadc6359681609f4799034ad5cade3e1b31864f25fe12f

this is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html
from datetime import datetime

data = {'UserName': 'username',
           'Password': 'password',
           'IsMobileUser': 'false',
           'ReturnUrl': '',
           'RequireCaptcha': 'false'
           }

login_url = 'https://dienynas.tamo.lt/Prisijungimas/Login'
url = 'https://dienynas.tamo.lt/Pranesimai'

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(login_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    AUTH_TOKEN = soup.select_one("input[name=SToken]")["value"]
    now = datetime.now()
    data['Timestamp'] = f'{now.year}-{now.month}-{now.day} {now.hour}:{now.minute}:{now.second}'
    data["SToken"] = AUTH_TOKEN
    r = s.post(login_url, data=data)
    r = s.get(url)
    print(r.text)
```

And I cant login to the page, I think I did Timestamp wrong? Please help :)

Edit: so today i changed my code a little bit because i found out that most data i need were in hidden inputs so:

```
data = {'UserName': 'username',
        'Password': 'password',
        }

AUTH_TOKEN = soup.find("input",{'name':"SToken"}).get("value")
    Timestamp = soup.find("input",{'name':"Timestamp"}).get("value")
    IsMobileUser = soup.find("input",{'name':"IsMobileUser"}).get("value")
    RequireCaptcha = soup.find("input", {'name': "RequireCaptcha"}).get("value")
    ReturnUrl = soup.find("input", {'name': "ReturnUrl"}).get("value")
```

and added this to data dictionary, i also tried to create headers:

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
r = s.post(login_url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

and yeah nothing works for me.. Maybe there is a way to find out why I cant login?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you .It seems you are not sending the correct timestamp .
The website has an input for it so you can scrape it like the token and send it or you can generate the same timestamp with the same time zone the website is using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone


data = {'UserName': 'username',
           'Password': 'password',
           'IsMobileUser': 'false',
           'ReturnUrl': '',
           'RequireCaptcha': 'false'
           }

login_url = 'https://dienynas.tamo.lt/Prisijungimas/Login'
url = 'https://dienynas.tamo.lt/Pranesimai'

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(login_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    AUTH_TOKEN = soup.find("input",{'name':"SToken"}).get("value")
    Timestamp  = soup.find("input",{'name':"Timestamp"}).get("value") #2020-03-31 15:36:37
    now = datetime.now(timezone('Etc/GMT-3'))
    data['Timestamp'] = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') #2020-03-31 15:36:36
    print('Timestamp from website',Timestamp)
    print('Timestamp from python',data['Timestamp'])
    data["SToken"] = AUTH_TOKEN
    r = s.post(login_url, data=data)
    r = s.get(url)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: Yeah you were right, I wasnt using the right Timestamp, but still cant login when changed code a bit with your help

Comment: @EimantasG I tried to create an account to test with but I couldn't . Won't know for sure what's wrong until I test .

Comment: yeah i dont think you can create an account on this website, but if you need any information you can ask it, I will try to figure it out and give it to you

Comment: Thanks for your help! I dont know how but now my code runs perfectly and i havent changed anything, i just ran it from another .py file